# Can an input be the same as the target with arcpy.Append?

Tags: arcpy, merge, python-2.7, append

I am basically trying to append the records of one feature class to another using `arcpy.Append_management`. They have similar but different schemas (they both have a `uniqueid` column but they also have columns that completely do not match).

```
osm_gdb = r"...\OSM_Differential.gdb"
osm_bing_diff_uniqueid = os.path.join(osm_gdb, "osm_bing_diff_uniqueid")
BldgFP_Parcels_20190909_gdb = "...\\BldgFP_Parcels_20190909.gdb"
osm_bing_diff_uniqueid_Layer = "osm_bing_diff_uniqueid_Layer"

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = BldgFP_Parcels_20190909_gdb

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    state_abb = fc[:2]
    if state_abb == 'DE':
        state_feature = os.path.join(BldgFP_Parcels_20190909_gdb, fc)

        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(osm_bing_diff_uniqueid, osm_bing_diff_uniqueid_Layer, "'st_abbr' = '{}'".format(state_abb))
        arcpy.Append_management([osm_bing_diff_uniqueid_Layer, state_feature], state_feature, "NO_TEST", "", "")
        print("{} done!".format(state_abb))
```

Basically, I get the following error:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000572: The output cannot be the same as input.
Failed to execute (Append).
```

Will this just not work using `Append`? Should I just be using `Merge` instead? I am trying to keep from creating a new `gdb` and `feature classes` for the output. I really just wanted to add the rows from `osm_bing_diff_uniqueid_Layer` to `state_feature`.

Comment: I dont follow your workflow, do the two inputs have common geometry? Your workflow sounds more like you want to Join Fields or a Spatial Join. But I'm having trouble understanding exactly...

Comment: They are both polygons of building footprints. One was produced from Bing datasets and the other from an OSM source. They do not match up spatially; I am essentially trying to add them together with the field attributes of both combined into one table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve, but your code seems to be trying to append `state_feature` to `state_feature`.  As the error message says, this is not possible.  You cannot append a dataset to itself.

If you want to append `osm_bing_diff_uniqueid_Layer` to `state_feature`, then you should change this:

`arcpy.Append_management([osm_bing_diff_uniqueid_Layer, state_feature], state_feature, "NO_TEST", "", "")`

To this:

`arcpy.Append_management(osm_bing_diff_uniqueid_Layer, state_feature, "NO_TEST", "", "")`

If you want to achieve something else, then you need to reword you question to make it clearer.

Comment: This worked but as it turned out I had an issue with my `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management` expression. I had to change `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(osm_bing_diff_uniqueid, osm_bing_diff_uniqueid_Layer, "'st_abbr' = '{}'".format(state_abb))` to `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(osm_bing_diff_uniqueid, osm_bing_diff_uniqueid_Layer, "st_abbr = '{}'".format(state_abb))` (without the quotes around 'st_abbr').